# Using Google API to Query Date in Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a google sheet that looks something like:

```
date        title  quantity
01/01/2015  t1     1
02/01/2015  t2     5
```

I am trying to write a query to return a row using a ListQuery.  It works for strings or integers e.g.

```
listQuery.SpreadsheetQuery = "title=\"t1\""; 
listQuery.SpreadsheetQuery = "quantity=5";
```

However, when I try to do the same thing with the date column it doesn't match anything.  I've tried a number of different ways e.g.

```
listQuery.SpreadsheetQuery = "date=\"01/01/2015\""; 
listQuery.SpreadsheetQuery = "date=01/01/2015"; 
listQuery.SpreadsheetQuery = "date=new Date(2015,1,1)";
```

but none of them return a result.  Does anyone know how I can query a row based on a cell containing a date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in-case someone else has the same issue, after some playing around with this I discovered the date in the query needs to be formatted as yyyy-MM-dd (regardless of how the date is formatted in the spreadsheet) e.g.

```
listQuery.SpreadsheetQuery = "date=2015-01-05";
```

Comment: Thank you. I bit unrelated, but your question actually answered my question. I was getting HTTP 400 - Bad Request from trying to query for an email address, and escaping quotes around the email address works.